# A Control is an observer of an object and I it fails to register because window handle has not been created

Tags: c#, winforms, observer-pattern

I have a windows forms control `MyControl` which is an observer of an object. The object has some images. The control has `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar`. On registering the object notifies the control of the images and the control increments the value of the progress bar, which throws "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created". This control is inside another control which is inside a window and all of this is happening in a chain of constructors.

My understanding is that registering should happen *after* the window is created, but I don't think I can do it with the current architecture. I used to just ask the object of images count in the constructor, but the images are added asynchronously, so I don't want to rely on counters anymore.

```
interface IImagesObserver
{
  void onImageAdded();
}
```

```
class MyControl : IImagesObserver
{
  public MyControl(MyObject object)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    object.register(this);
  }

  void IObjectOnserver.onImageAdded()
  {
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      progressBar.Value++;
      Invalidate();
    });
  }
}
```

```
class MyObject
{
  public void register(IImagesObserver observer)
  {
    foreach( var img in images)
      observer.onImageAdded();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override [OnHandleCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onhandlecreated?view=net-5.0) and call the register method from there. Or you can force the creation of the control handle in the constructor with [CreateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_CreateControl).
You should also unregister your observer before it gets disposed. An override of the [Control.Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dispose?view=net-5.0) method would be a good place for this (before you call `base.Dispose`).